# 2005 nissan Altima often will not start on the first try. Any ideas why?

Tags: starting, nissan

Lately when I try to start the car for the first time it will not start. It clicks once but will not turn over. It may start the next time or sometimes it will take 2 or three times of the same thing before it finally starts. So far it has eventually been starting but I am concerned that sooner or later it will not start and leave my wife stranded somewhere. we replaced the starter and the catalytic converter within the last year for other reasons.

Comment: How old is your battery?

Comment: Either battery or starter needs replaced.

Comment: Sounds like the starter. Or battery